# Can anyone explain this rails routes code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is the code in config/routes.rb
So we have brands and products controllers with action index and show action. But why products controller is inside brands controller. Can anyone explain it to me?
And next we have basket controller with show update and destroy action. But what is `resolve("Basket") { route_for(:basket) }` means?

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :brands, only: [:index, :show] do
    resources :products, only: [:index, :show]
  end

  resource :basket, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  resolve("Basket") { route_for(:basket) }
end
```

Comment: See the docs for [Nested Resources](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) and [Using `resolve`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-resolve).

Comment: use command rails routes > routes.txt, Now open the routes.txt and read the file everything will get explain what is where but why only developer who wrote it will can explain  it.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove `resolve("Basket") { route_for(:basket)`, your url to basket will be:

```
.../baskets/:id
```

So, with `resolve("Basket") { route_for(:basket) }` or `resolve("Basket") { [:basket] }`, your url to basket is singular, not plural:

```
.../basket
```

PS We have only one basket, one profile and this way make it possible for urls

<kbd>[documentation](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-resolve)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. And what happens if I don't use resolve. Just only use "resource :basket". And can I use " resource :baskets" this too?

Comment: @AkshitThakurAk For all cases that you discribed, I think your basket will be in other urls(path with 's' and with id). So, you can try all your prefers step by step and see what will be happened with basket paths. You can see paths that changing by command: rails routes https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html